# Disallow traffic from VPN

Tags: linux, security, networking, vpn

I've game server and I want block all VPN traffics via iptables or other fast application for Linux (without desktop). I don't know, how to do that. Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set restriction for countries (max 10) via IP tables, or you can allow only specific countries *(max 10)*.

You have another option - to block incoming ports what VPN protocol uses. I would prefer combination of both options.

you can find closer information here for example :

https://terminal28.com/how-to-block-countries-using-iptables-debian/ (this is not my blog, but I used this in the past)

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/rrasblog/2006/06/14/which-ports-to-unblock-for-vpn-traffic-to-pass-through/

**UPDATE**
I did some investigate and you are probably able to set to *whitelist* only one country, sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: How to allow only specific countries?

Comment: **barwnikk** , this should be helpful for you. http://evilware.com/20130315/linux/block-all-countries-except-the-usa-in-iptables-script.html

Answer (score 0):

You would need a list of IPs that you are trying to block.  There is no magical command that knows to block traffic unless you provide it a specific IP.

Also I am a little confused as to what you are trying to do.  Are you trying to block people from using anonymizing proxy/VPN services?

Comment: Yes, but there are a lot of proxies.

Comment: Yes there are and sadly it is almost a fruitless action.  You either need to make a list of all BAD IPs to block or a list of all GOOD IPs to whitelist.